# SQL: case clause in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query where i need to show the values that have either start date more than a year ago or start date = Null.

I have done "more than a year ago" part but i am not sure how to consolidate it with start date = null

do i need to use case statement?

```
Select
    T0.JOBID
  , T0.JOBTITLE
  , T0.STATUS
  , T0.STARTDATE
  , T0.ENTEREDDATE
From
    ENPRISE_JOBCOST_JOB T0
Where
    T0.STATUS Not In (7, 8) AND
    T0.STARTDATE <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: It is MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `NULL` check to the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
WHERE
    T0.STATUS NOT IN (7, 8) AND
    (T0.STARTDATE <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) OR TO.STARTDATE IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select T0.JOBID , T0.JOBTITLE , T0.STATUS , T0.STARTDATE , T0.ENTEREDDATE 
   From ENPRISE_JOBCOST_JOB T0
     Where T0.STATUS Not In (7, 8) 
      AND (T0.STARTDATE <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) OR T0.STARTDATE IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Answer (score 0):

Add `OR T0.STARTDATE is null`. Make sure you add parenthesis around the whole predicate:

```
Select
    T0.JOBID
  , T0.JOBTITLE
  , T0.STATUS
  , T0.STARTDATE
  , T0.ENTEREDDATE
From
    ENPRISE_JOBCOST_JOB T0
Where
  T0.STATUS Not In (7, 8) AND
  (T0.STARTDATE <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()) OR T0.STARTDATE is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Select
T0.JOBID
, T0.JOBTITLE
, T0.STATUS
, T0.STARTDATE
, T0.ENTEREDDATE
From
ENPRISE_JOBCOST_JOB T0
Where
T0.STATUS Not In (7, 8) AND
(T0.STARTDATE <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE() OR T0.STARTDATE is null)

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). Also, please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.